# Nesting of inline static class variables leads to run-time crash

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, inline

Given the following classes :

```
// Header file 'A' //

struct A
{
  A (void) { /* do some internal initialization */ }
} ;

struct B
{
  inline static A pool_of_a [10] { } ;

  B (void) { /* grab an 'A' from 'pool_of_a' */ }
~ B (void) { /* free an 'A' to   'pool_of_a' */ }
}

// Header file 'C' //

#include "header_A.h"

struct C
{
  inline static B b_array [5] { } ; 
} ;
```

When I create and instance of type 'C', the run-time code crashes before 'main' is entered.

From what I can tell, it appears that 'C::b_array' is initializing before 'B::pool_of_a'.

I have confirmed that 'A' and 'B' work perfectly on their own, but when I attempt to create the array of 'B' in 'C', things crash.

If I change class 'C' code to the following, it works perfectly :

```
// Header file 'C' //

#include "header_A.h"

struct C
{
  inline static B * b_array = nullptr ;

  C (void) 
    { 
      if (b_array == nullptr)
        {
          static B b_array [5] { } ; 

          C :: b_array = b_array ;   
        }
    } ;
```

The change, as I understand it, is that 'b_array' is only getting initialized when 'C' constructor is called.  All instances of 'C' in my code happen after 'main' is called, so this guarantees 'pool_of_a' will be initialized before 'b_array'.

I am aware of the "global initialization order fiasco", but given the relative newness of 'inline' global/static variables, I am not yet clear on the exact rules of initialization order.

I can't seem to find any clear explanation/definition of what the ordering is supposed to be for my particular scenario.

Hints, tips, answers, or links to answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The exact rules here are: there are no rules. There is no defined initialization order, and, as such, you cannot rely on one.

Comment: `inline`does not guard against "the fiasco".

Comment: `Hints, tips, answers, or links to answers will be greatly appreciated.` - avoid mutable static or global variables. [cppcoreguidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#i22-avoid-complex-initialization-of-global-objects)

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order